# SAP HYBRIS : how to use media to convert csv file to media hmc

Tags: cron, media, sap-commerce-cloud

I am a beginner in the Sap Hybris. I created a CronJob that works perfectly. which returns all the products with status approved and generated CSV file in local C://...

But I want to create or convert my CSV file to a media in HMC MEDIA? can someone help me?

I already have gone through Hybris wiki but I didn't understand.

Thank u for all !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this, you only need to create your Media object, and attach your file to the created object, something like :

```
private MediaModel createMedia(final File file) throws MediaIOException, IllegalArgumentException, FileNotFoundException
{

    final CatalogVersionModel catalogVersion = catalogVersionService.getCatalogVersion("MY_MEDIA_CATALOG", "VERSION");

    MediaModel mediaModel;

    try
    {
        mediaModel = mediaService.getMedia(catalogVersion, file.getName());
    }
    catch (final UnknownIdentifierException e)
    {
        mediaModel = modelService.create(MediaModel.class);
    }

    mediaModel.setCode(file.getName());
    mediaModel.setCatalogVersion(catalogVersion);
    mediaModel.setMime("text/csv");
    mediaModel.setRealFileName(file.getName());
    modelService.save(mediaModel);
    mediaService.setStreamForMedia(mediaModel, new FileInputStream(file));

    //Remove file
    FileUtils.removeFile(file);

    return mediaModel;
}
```